# Django Filter distinct field from multiple table

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to filter distinct field from multiple table. for example user input is "python,web developer". I want to display both "python" keyskills matched jobs and "web developer" title matched jobs.

```
In User table

id  |  username  |  password
-----------------------------
1   |  employer1 |  sffddgfd
2   |  employer2 |  dfggfgfd

In Company Table

id  |  emp_id  |  companyname
-----------------------------
1   |    1     |  abc
2   |    2     |  xyz



In jobs table

+----+--------+--------------------+
| id | emp_id | title              |
+----+--------+--------------------+
|  1 |      1 | Software Developer |
|  2 |      1 | Software Developer |
|  3 |      1 | testing            |
|  4 |      1 | webdeveloper       |
|  5 |      2 | Software Developer |
|  6 |      2 | testing            |
|  7 |      2 | software           |
+----+--------+--------------------+

In employerkeyskills table

+----+--------+--------+--------------------+
| id | emp_id | job_id | keyskills          |
+----+--------+--------+--------------------+
|  1 |      1 |      2 | python             |
|  2 |      1 |      2 | django             |
|  3 |      1 |      2 | html               |
|  4 |      1 |      3 | manual testing     |
|  5 |      1 |      3 | automation testing |
|  6 |      1 |      4 | css                |
|  7 |      1 |      4 | javascript         |
|  8 |      1 |      4 | html               |
|  9 |      1 |      4 | php                |
| 10 |      2 |      5 | python             |
| 11 |      2 |      5 | php                |
| 12 |      2 |      6 | SQL                |
| 13 |      2 |      6 | Manual Testing     |
| 14 |      2 |      7 | sql                |
| 15 |      2 |      7 | testing            |
| 16 |      2 |      7 | python             |
| 17 |      2 |      7 | html               |
+----+--------+--------+--------------------+
```

*models.py*

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class company(models.Models):
    emp = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
    companyname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class jobs(models.Model):
    emp = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class employerkeyskills(models.Model):
    emp=models.ForeignKey(User,unique=False)
    job=models.ForeignKey(jobs,unique=False)
    keyskills=models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

*views.py*

```
details = employerkeyskills.objects.filter(keyskills__icontains=search)
```

using the above command i got duplicate result, at first I filtered with only keyskills. But same job repeat twice. i want to filter diplicate field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split input string first:

```
key_skill, title = "python,web developer".split(',')
```

Then filter jobs cross models:

```
jobs = Job.objects.filter(title=title, employerkeyskills__keyskills=key_skill)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
details = employerkeyskills.objects.filter(keyskills__icontains=search).distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
jobs.object.filter(employerkeyskills_set__keyskills__in = ["python", "web developer"])
```

If you add a related_name arg:

```
class employerkeyskills(models.Model):
    emp=models.ForeignKey(User,unique=False)
    job=models.ForeignKey(jobs,unique=False, related_name='skills')
    keyskills=models.CharField(max_length=50)

jobs.object.filter(skills__keyskills__in = ["python", "web developer"])
```